# 3 month old kitten pawing at mouth and making gagging motion

Tags: cats, health, veterinarian, upper-respiratory-disease, teething

My 3 month old male kitten woke up from his evening nap yesterday and started pawing at his mouth with both front paws (nearly falling on his face) and then did kind of a gagging motion with his mouth and about 3 seconds later he did it again. Then he started licking his lips way more than he normally does. I did notice that when he's licking his lips, he's also clicking his tongue. That was around midnight last night and he's still doing it now. It only happens when he's upright - either sitting on all fours or walking. It doesn't happen when he lays down. It happens every 10-15 minutes if he's not laying down. He's eating and drinking just fine. He's playing like normal. I checked his gums and he's got a molar coming in on each side of his mouth - I can only just see the tiny points on them that popped through. He's also just getting over an upper respiratory infection and still has a runny nose. Is this teething or if this something more serious? We have an appointment with the vet for tomorrow afternoon but will take him to the emergency vet if that's what he needs. Thanks!

Comment: i think you need to get him to the vet now as this does not sound normal,it is better to take him to the vet one time too many than it is to regret not taking him for a long time.it is hard to tell if this is serious or not on the net.